# Gulp Build fails on Yeoman gulp-angular

Tags: angularjs, gulp, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've been running through the gulp-angular generator.

Tried other answers by doing a complete uninstall of npm bower etc and reinstalling.

I do not get any errors when going through the generator but as soon as I try running 'gulp build', I keep getting this error

```
gulp build
[09:16:28] Using gulpfile ~/app/gulpfile.js
[09:16:28] Starting 'scripts'...
[09:16:28] Starting 'styles'...
[09:16:29] Starting 'partials'...
[09:16:29] Starting 'fonts'...
[09:16:29] Starting 'other'...
[09:16:29] gulp-inject 2 files into index.scss.
[09:16:30] Finished 'partials' after 1.28 s
[09:16:30] gulp-ruby-sass: directory
[09:16:30] gulp-ruby-sass: write index.css
  write index.css.map
[09:16:30] all files 13.84 kB
[09:16:30] Finished 'scripts' after 2.08 s
[09:16:31] Finished 'styles' after 2.03 s
[09:16:31] Starting 'inject'...
[09:16:31] gulp-inject 1 files into index.html.
[09:16:31] Finished 'other' after 1.61 s
[09:16:31] Finished 'fonts' after 1.68 s
[09:16:31] gulp-inject 10 files into index.html.
[09:16:31] Finished 'inject' after 142 ms
[09:16:31] Starting 'html'...
[09:16:31] gulp-inject 1 files into index.html.
[09:16:31] dist/ maps/styles/app-070ae8ae0a.css.map 13.48 kB
[09:16:32] dist/ maps/styles/vendor-2a1d35e48e.css.map 273.03 kB
[09:16:33] dist/ maps/scripts/app-6e2669f540.js.map 14.81 kB

events.js:142
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: scripts/vendor-70aa324478.js: error: couldn't process source due to parse error
Unexpected token (49992:4)
```

I thought it's in that file, script/vendor ... but I figured out that it was generated by gulp.

Here is my Gulp file.

```
/**
 *  Welcome to your gulpfile!
 *  The gulp tasks are splitted in several files in the gulp directory
 *  because putting all here was really too long
 */

'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var wrench = require('wrench');

/**
 *  This will load all js or coffee files in the gulp directory
 *  in order to load all gulp tasks
*/
wrench.readdirSyncRecursive('./gulp').filter(function(file) {
return (/\.(js|coffee)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function(file) {
  require('./gulp/' + file);
});


/**
 *  Default task clean temporaries directories and launch the
 *  main optimization build task
*/
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
gulp.start('build');
});
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, do you have any scripts with syntax errors? It looks like it's throwing on whatever the `'html'` task is.

Comment: Ended up removing node and all npm dependencies, yo, gulp etc. Started from scratch removed all the errors the second time around!